# Regex pattern, optional plus character at start of line not matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to control a text input field in a react application by only allowing an empty string, digits or an optional plus character at the start.

The regex pattern I am using is the following:

```
export const phoneNumberTestPattern = new RegExp('^\\+?\\d+?$');
```

This pattern is used to test the inputs value whenever the input is changed

```
onChange={ (e) => {
    if (e.target.value === '' || phoneNumberTestPattern.test(e.target.value)) {
       field.onChange(e.target.value);
   }
}}
```

The pattern is working correctly for allowing only digits. But the optional plus character at the start is not being matched when the onChange event parameter returns a `+` value as `e.target.value`.

The `event.target.value` does return the `+` as a value when typed in, but the test pattern does not recognize it as something that matches so the `field.onChange` method is never fired.

I dont understand what the reason for this is, and why the pattern is not matching a plus character at the start of the string being sent to it. Could it be possible the value I am sending to the test pattern is a string and I am trying to match it against a plus operator ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that you use the regex against a single character. You need to use the whole input string as the input text for the `RegExp#test` method. All the four answers are useless here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the whole input is being tested against. e.target.value includes the value of the whole input not just a single character.

Comment: Can you share a JS fiddle? The regex is correct to match a string with just numbers with an optional `+` at the start, so the problem is with the code, not the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on `\d+?`. It does not mean an optional sequence of digits. It means a sequence of at least one digit, not greedy.

The `*` and `+` quantifiers are, by default, greedy. This means that they attempt to match as much as possible.

For example, the regex `a+` matches the entire string `aaa`. The `+` qualifier makes the `a` before it to match all `a` characters from the input string.
By adding a `?` after `+`, the qualifier becomes lazy and the regex `a+?` matches only the first `a` from the input string.

Check it below:

```js
const reGreedy = /a+/;
const reLazy = /a+?/;

console.log(reGreedy.exec('aaa'));
console.log(reLazy.exec('aaa'));
```

This means that your regex matches the input string only if the input string contains at least one digit at the end.

There are two ways to achieve what you need. One of them is to wrap `\d+` in parentheses, like this: `(\d+)?`. This way `\d+` matches a sequence of one or more digits and the `?` after it tells that this sequence is optional.

The same thing can be achieved by using `*` instead of `+`, and `?` is not needed any more in this case. `\d*` matches a sequence of zero or more digits.

Also, if you create a `RegExp` using a [regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#literal_notation_and_constructor) there is no need to escape the backslash.

Be aware that this regex also matches the empty string (now both the `+` and the number are optional). Your check against the empty string can be removed from the code.

All in all, your code should be like:

```js
export const phoneNumberTestPattern = /^\+?\d*$/;

onChange={ (e) => {
    if (phoneNumberTestPattern.test(e.target.value)) {
       field.onChange(e.target.value);
   }
}}
```

Check the regex [online](https://regex101.com/r/acMRy9/1).

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed explanation. Regex is not something I have much understanding of, and could not see the mistake. I am going over your answer and hope to spend more time to learn regex. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe u can try this regex pattern

> ^(?:+)?\d+$

Comment: Thankyou, this syntax is not recognized as a valid regex pattern in Javascript I believe. Would it be possible to please explain what the pattern is doing different from the one I am trying so i could try to replicate it in Javascript regex syntax

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Like other answers say, you could use `/^(?:|\+?\d+)$/`

```js
const populated = '+123456'
const unpopulated = ''

const pattern = /^(?:|\+?\d+)$/

console.log(`populated: ${pattern.test(populated)}`)
console.log(`unpopulated: ${pattern.test(unpopulated)}`)
```

But an alternative is to use the `pattern` attribute of the `<input>` tag:

```css
input:valid {
    background-color: palegreen;
}

input:invalid {
    background-color: lightpink;
}
```

```html
<input id="id-inp" type="tel" pattern="^\+?\d+?$">
```

Comment: `/^\+?\d+$/` = `new RegExp('^\\+?\\d+?$')` in what the regex delivers, so it is not going to help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew could you expand? I don't understand why you say it is not going to help?

Comment: Your solution is not doing what OP needs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thanks, assume you mean empty string? I had missed that when reading OP question. Have edited my answer